# Access class from another package

Tags: java, java-package

I have two folders in a folder called asdsad

```
.
├── a
│   └── A.java
├── b
│   └── B.java
```

This is my A.java

```
package asdsad.a;

public class A {
    public A() {

    }

    public int number;
}
```

This is my B.java

```
package asdsad.b;
import asdsad.a.A;

public class B {
    public B() {

    }

    public int n = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.number);
    }
}
```

Now I'm in my terminal inside asdsad folder. I execute `javac a/A.java`, I don't have any errors. But when I try to `javac b/B.java`, I get these errors:

```
b/B.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
import asdsad.a.A;
               ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: package asdsad
b/B.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        A a = new A();
        ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: class B
b/B.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        A a = new A();
              ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: class B
3 errors
```

Comment: `cd ..` `javac asdsad/*/*.java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I'm in my terminal inside asdsad folder

Wrong already. You should be in the folder that contains it. One up.

> I execute javac a/A.java, I don't have any errors.

But you're still wrong. You should have executed `javac asdsad/a/A.java`.

> But when I try to javac b/B.java

Wrong again. It should have been `javac asdsad/b/B.java`.